# Query returning wrong values

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I'm testing and studying Neptune with Gremlin.
I have created a few nodes of type User that simply have an `id` and an `email`.
If I make a raw query for them I get:

```
// http://my-neptune/?gremlin=g.V().hasLabel('User')

  "result": {
    "data": {
      "@type": "g:List",
      "@value": [
        {
          "@type": "g:Vertex",
          "@value": {
            "id": "u01",
            "label": "User",
            "properties": {
              "email": [
                {
                  "@type": "g:VertexProperty",
                  "@value": {
                    "id": {
                      "@type": "g:Int32",
                      "@value": 2051025270
                    },
                    "value": "User01@email.com",
                    "label": "email"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "@type": "g:Vertex",
          "@value": {
            "id": "u02",
            "label": "User",
            "properties": {
              "email": [
                {
                  "@type": "g:VertexProperty",
                  "@value": {
                    "id": {
                      "@type": "g:Int32",
                      "@value": -374298315
                    },
                    "value": "user02@mail.com",
                    "label": "email"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I wan't to represent this graph using [visjs](https://visjs.org/). So I would like to return basically 3 properties for each node:

- ID
- Label (which is shown in the node, and I would like a format like `id - mail`)
- Group (to group the nodes by color and shape)

To do so, I'm executing the following query:

```
g.V()
    .hasLabel('User')
    .project('id', 'label', 'group')
    .by(T.id)
    .by(
        union(id(), values('email'))
        .fold()
    )
    .by(T.label)
```

But the result is not as expected. I get the projection for `label` right only for the first node and empty for the others:

```
  "result": {
    "data": {
      "@type": "g:List",
      "@value": [
        {
          "@type": "g:Map",
          "@value": [
            "id",
            "u01",
            "label",
            {
              "@type": "g:List",
              "@value": [
                "u01",
                "User01@email.com"
              ]
            },
            "group",
            "User"
          ]
        },
        {
          "@type": "g:Map",
          "@value": [
            "id",
            "u02",
            "group",
            "User",
            "label",
            {
              "@type": "g:List",
              "@value": [
                // This list should not be empty 
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Any ideas why this happens or how could I execute a similar task?

Comment: Your by() statements look out of order, should the second one be `by(T.label)`

Comment: Please could you explain more about how you want to group, 'by color and shape' is confusing me as they are not properties on the user vertex

Comment: Hi James. Color and shape are properties for VisJS. It's nothing to do with the graph database itself. The `by()` is not out of order. I'm returning the properties so VisJS can draw the graph. In VisJS the `label` property has different meaning than in the database. While the database uses it to "group", VisJS use it to show the text for the vertice.

Comment: My point is: don't focus on the VisJS part. The weird part is that for the second node I get an emtpy list in my `label` projection for aparently no reason :s

Comment: could you indicate how would like the output to look, maybe in json if you're not so familar with how gremlin can output results?

Comment: The format is fine. Thing is there is missing data on the output. I added a comment on the last JSON `This list should not be empty`. Thing is, with that query, gremlin is giving me only the first result "right". The ones after have the `label` projection empty and I don't understand why it is empty

Comment: by coincidence I have 'user' vertices also with an 'email' property, your traversal ran fine from the console for both gremlin-server and neptune, output like: 

==>{id=64730590-f661-4ddc-bb4d-1ef01a78856f, label=[64730590-f661-4ddc-bb4d-1ef01a78856f, me@megumi.tadokoro.co.jp], group=user}
==>{id=fb5293d8-246b-4549-b665-d16e905117f3, label=[fb5293d8-246b-4549-b665-d16e905117f3, me@senzaemon.nakiri.co.jp], group=user}
==>{id=7ca8b90d-e625-4cfe-8bce-ad141ef1e66f, label=[7ca8b90d-e625-4cfe-8bce-ad141ef1e66f, me@ryōko.sakaki.co.jp], group=user}

Comment: That's really odd :/
What version of Neptune are you using?

Comment: "dbEngineVersion":"1.0.1.0.200463.0"

Comment: Mine is `Neptune 1.0.2.1`, `db.r5`. Still getting this "wrong" result hmm... Will try a different query

Comment: This looks like a potential bug in the latest engine release. You can take a snapshot and restore to a previous release 1.0.2.0. We are working on a fix.

Comment: Please try updating your Neptune instance to this version: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/engine-releases-1.0.2.1.R4.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an answer so that the solution proposed in the comments can be accepted if the new version mentioned did resolve the issue.

Upgrading the Neptune instance to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/engine-releases-1.0.2.1.R4.html should resolve the issue.